# Run Python script when I log into my system? [xubuntu 15.04]

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, xubuntu

How can i run a python script at startup with xubuntu 15.04?
I want to run a script that reminds me of things,like backup,buying thing,calling somebody.
I already have the script,i just need it to start at startup. 
(Python 3.4)
As far i know, xubuntu 15.04 uses systemd.
All the tutorials i found,are for init.d or upstart.
I need one for systemd

Comment: Does this help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd

Comment: Does your script print on the terminal or does it open its own windows? Do we need to start a terminal automatically for it once xubuntu shows you as logged in?

Comment: It opens it's own window (made in tkinter) so no terminal neded

Comment: OK but you definitely need X Windows running, so don't stick it in `/etc/rc.local` as is.  You can play games with forking a subprocess that sleeps for a while on the gamble that X will be running by then, and stick that in `/etc/rc.local` but there is a cleaner way to do it, probably in that answer about Gnome.

Comment: I running XFCE,not Gnome

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right.

Comment: @jonrsharpe xubuntu has XFCE in it, not Gnome.  Care to reopen?

Comment: Here's some answers for XFCE.  https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5550  http://askubuntu.com/questions/77066/modify-xfce-startup-applications

Comment: Ok,found the answer,  Configuration/Systemsettings/Session and Startup. Thanks @Paul

Comment: You can always post a self-answer.   Others might benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
You have to go  Configuration/Systemsettings/Session and Startup,
and add the program.